# FullCalendar - Events gets data from API and seems correct, but not displayed in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

First or all.. i have browsed through tons of material and examples on this, but i cannot figure it out eitherhow..

**Scenario :**

Running on ASP.NET using Web Api 2...

API is called to fetch events, objects seems legit : 
[image]

Issue seems to be that callback is never true..

**Code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: function (start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",    //WebMethods will not allow GET
                url: "api/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/" + getQueryVariable("teamid"),
                //completely take out 'data:' line if you don't want to pass to webmethod - Important to also change webmethod to not accept any parameters 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (doc) {
                    var events = [];   //javascript event object created here
                    
                    var obj = doc;
                    $(obj).each(function () {                          
                            events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),  //your calevent object has identical parameters 'title', 'start', ect, so this will work
                            start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed into DateTime object    
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            id: $(this).attr('id')
                        });
                    });                     
                    if (callback) callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Should really be `if (typeof callback == 'function')`, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Also, you can't reference your `calendar` variable by name from within its declaration, and you haven't included jQuery or FullCalendar in your snippet. Please look in DevTools for problems first, then edit your original post and try again if you still have issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @J.Titus :) 

That's right.. i forgot to add them to the snippet example in stackoveflow. Had everything inplace for my dev environment though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official doc https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/, function for programmatically generating Event Objects

```
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }
```

You should replace your events function with this:

```
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",    //WebMethods will not allow GET
                url: "api/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/" + getQueryVariable("teamid"),
                //completely take out 'data:' line if you don't want to pass to webmethod - Important to also change webmethod to not accept any parameters 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (doc) {
                    var events = [];   //javascript event object created here

                    var obj = doc;
                    $(obj).each(function () {                          
                            events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),  //your calevent object has identical parameters 'title', 'start', ect, so this will work
                            start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed into DateTime object    
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            id: $(this).attr('id')
                        });
                    });                     
                    if (callback) callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
```

Because when you are calling with three parameters, fourth param callback is empty, that's the reason of not getting events.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @shi.. Small stuff like this, can be really, really annoying since it's prolly one of the last places you care to look.. hehe :) Works like a charm now !